# mlx90640 how to connect

Tags: hardware

I brought a mlx90640 to connect to a raspberry pi.  I have never connected something to a raspberry pi before and I don't know where to connect it or what cables I need.

The device looks like this:

[image: Front]
[image: back]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is a "mlx90640"? It looks like it supports I²C and serial - what does the data sheet show?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.melexis.com/-/media/files/documents/datasheets/mlx90640-datasheet-melexis.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiiudDkg6ThAhXXi54KHcIDCY0QFjADegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2scCWf0iLnKDyXxKTM2xhF

Comment: It's a thermal camera with 24x32 pixels.